# Choose 14 combinations from 100 including all the numbers found in the list, and taking into account their frequency of appearance

Tags: bash, combinations

I can't finish this script. Could you help me?

Either a list of 100 combinations composed of 5 numbers ranging from 1 to 49. The purpose of this script is to choose 14 of these combinations in an equiporportional way, i.e. by including all the numbers found in the list, and by taking into account their frequency of occurrence.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Either a list of 100 combinations composed of 5 numbers ranging from 1 to 49. The purpose of this script is to choose 14 of these combinations in an equiporportional way, i.e. by including all the numbers found in the list, and by taking into account their frequency of occurrence.

numbers=() #table to store numbers
for (( i=1; i<=50; i++ )); do
 numbers+=(0) #for each number (from 1 to 49), its number of occurrences is initialized to zero.
done
while IFS=',' read -r num_1 num_2 num_3 num_4 num_5 proba_total proba_50; do #Loop to count the frequency of appearance of numbers in each combination
  numbers[$num_1]=$(echo "${numbers[$num_1]} + 1" | bc)
  numbers[$num_2]=$(echo "${numbers[$num_2]} + 1" | bc)
  numbers[$num_3]=$(echo "${numbers[$num_3]} + 1" | bc)
  numbers[$num_4]=$(echo "${numbers[$num_4]} + 1" | bc)
  numbers[$num_5]=$(echo "${numbers[$num_5]} + 1" | bc)
done < ./tmp
count_numbers=0 #variable to store the number of unique numbers found
for (( i=1; i<=49; i++ )); do
  if [ ${numbers[$i]} -gt 0 ]; then #If the number has been found in at least one combination, it is counted
    echo "Numéro $i: trouvée dans ${numbers[$i]} combinaisons. Doit être présente dans: $(echo "scale=0; $(bc -l <<< "scale=10; $(echo "14/100*${numbers[$i]}" | bc -l)")/1" | bc -l) combinaisons sur 14." #The number is displayed on the screen, the number of times it has been found in the list of combinations, as well as its frequency of appearance rounded to the nearest integer: 14/100*${numbers[$i]} (knowing this frequency allows you to know how many of the 14 combinations will contain the number. Note that numbers less than 0.5 are rounded to Zero so they will not be selected to be in the final list).
    count_numbers=$((count_numbers+1))
  fi
done
echo
echo "Among the 100 combinations submitted, $count_numbers different numbers have been identified."
echo "Here is an equiproportional selection (14 combinations) in terms of frequency of appearance of all the numbers found in the list
:"
```

Content of tmp file (we use only the 5 1st columns, do not care about the 2 others values). In this exemple, the 100 combinatosn are only made of 16 differents numbers :

```
8,9,27,28,37,.00000006733472960649,1042634448565697025823.29223835702291394323
9,21,27,28,37,.00000007433230311830,816578840834854780620.13253676488983761033
8,9,21,27,28,.00000006642084702349,809583352099871759384.05331707930246135263
9,27,28,29,37,.00000005982349878999,800530309603058114263.12955413405628415282
6,9,27,28,37,.00000007677535066051,800164830173237853165.68451385478173226421
8,9,27,28,29,.00000005345626725995,793672305840536872484.65748459622627763414
6,8,9,27,28,.00000006860387217224,793309957409349354243.65941057807868650664
8,9,21,27,37,.00000006472830766877,768637109161657531107.36215020404453633090
9,27,28,37,38,.00000008008797293678,765950367200722139792.70808848724282392434
8,9,27,28,38,.00000007156392006835,759388603783204921837.34470299821797400650
8,9,27,29,37,.00000005209409197692,753530794822570333580.65275316963420871913
6,8,9,27,37,.00000006685570486120,753186772863701201928.68059602960855865670
9,27,28,36,37,.00000003432168134102,727853914382720354900.15532540758878547038
8,9,27,28,36,.00000003066870055556,721618516642592812941.04427522172377915669
8,9,27,37,38,.00000006974032466839,720981057266385504975.79715852947176227786
9,27,28,37,46,.00000005144956964138,718022526388470928972.97785383018648684494
8,9,27,28,46,.00000004597360570323,711871352437307481044.77587576701276610693
8,9,27,36,37,.00000002988719919004,685121265291608575149.31043507275577808827
8,9,27,37,46,.00000004480210397722,675867082757046931729.25940513590106310814
9,21,27,28,29,.00000005901156037548,621594665702391687553.43013182247200790357
6,9,21,27,28,.00000007573333777678,621310878741079917810.57774679751990516394
9,27,28,37,49,.00000004442255830508,614678394023520350905.01043018227203039752
8,9,27,28,49,.00000003969450462039,609412551258561144676.58410104523326163896
6,9,27,28,29,.00000006095106771602,609100022246271695262.14788563171252710286
7,9,27,28,37,.00000007444479121835,605182789838561454149.80337014063999988950
7,8,9,27,28,.00000006652136260785,599998294261143659553.68993902199947450672
9,21,27,28,38,.00000007900100037444,594744079934757091037.51330773951167761787
9,21,27,29,37,.00000005750782483469,590156313956482285380.80530485500334762951
6,9,21,27,37,.00000007380349706568,589886880069292444789.82126753661936208955
8,9,21,27,29,.00000005138705886617,585100547581320219884.62506487681855338656
6,8,9,21,27,.00000006594832371326,584833421887324228676.39262034659385409017
9,27,28,29,38,.00000006358092043491,583055350733788901897.78183793916738435592
6,9,27,28,38,.00000008159749196288,582789158767559040767.62734661030033784836
8,9,27,37,49,.00000003868300726306,578590333498391952651.15525467892911055788
6,9,27,29,37,.00000005939790955191,578293611245010343632.90742371286894491226
6,8,9,27,29,.00000005307597502506,573339470578273090908.31403107777688051328
7,8,9,27,37,.00000006482626190997,569652220746158360861.35522743767092811838
9,21,27,28,36,.00000003385585951356,565162999031530919194.51233471587012689512
9,21,27,37,38,.00000007698789292116,564663748465602707521.63668015584129901528
8,9,21,27,38,.00000006879379279072,559826372459868951918.89617650416784242267
9,21,27,28,46,.00000005075128413741,557529136502695279289.55156342081339103387
6,9,27,28,36,.00000003496858535285,553802685700155918271.01357691825459534638
9,27,29,37,38,.00000006196074823194,553566199338014782208.76998317905139074649
6,9,27,37,38,.00000007951822058074,553313470545019867022.55535333566508575555
8,9,27,29,38,.00000005536604150721,548823894103192244759.94482073114846514850
6,8,9,27,38,.00000007105480851801,548573330393758149895.64917257914602595971
9,27,28,29,46,.00000004084522149613,546571806588718629159.92064540053319477980
6,9,27,28,46,.00000005241930456425,546322271062291246273.25588036439036272563
9,21,27,36,37,.00000003299314280364,536578787908597598170.79193454897582606947
8,9,21,27,36,.00000002948156318386,531982010869398545389.96342190571381624838
9,27,28,36,38,.00000003647737318401,530122487859086803418.64868308115410484158
9,21,27,37,46,.00000004945803736995,529331022733236284942.26382949677300114065
6,9,27,36,37,.00000003407751410729,525793044383177958946.57397440934865598143
8,9,21,27,46,.00000004419403942056,524796336036209466212.41703875905369622354
9,27,28,38,46,.00000005468103771834,522961930280661839556.42505126510016346856
6,8,9,27,36,.00000003045052092438,521288666930592427701.60136424953761747976
9,27,29,37,46,.00000003980440151366,518927880959922515171.78106435240870101195
6,9,27,37,46,.00000005108355321662,518690966175090557706.84712106147803788961
8,9,27,29,46,.00000003556787497345,514482316166923041430.49883827271356944124
6,8,9,27,46,.00000004564654573150,514247430989797734450.13442289012972910533
8,9,21,28,37,.00000006230275852199,510605063807495101906.25762259740312578814
8,21,27,28,37,.00000006274360142252,509841688152476933474.00965151703414029002
9,27,36,37,38,.00000003554785493127,503310518321191790547.54841388196036742552
8,9,28,29,37,.00000005014198192031,500569950351395440607.19350166955691685548
6,8,9,28,37,.00000006435043624344,500341416818255016592.47976878334013986869
8,27,28,29,37,.00000005049677739442,499821577605378229220.75484908108824416688
6,8,27,28,37,.00000006480576813623,499593385739306779790.41679723157247181854
8,9,27,36,38,.00000003176436805201,498998744754398585476.38638656885447421481
9,27,37,38,46,.00000005328765277306,496512119783486692198.31239741466684797828
8,9,27,38,46,.00000004761605499358,492258586913131096818.63894368884260211659
9,27,28,37,40,.00000003491858014695,485235942921813566213.29465453782181982073
9,22,27,28,37,.00000003909687178847,485235942921813564272.35088284863398638337
8,9,22,27,28,.00000003493565019808,481079011095061875374.20935199698841867302
8,9,27,28,40,.00000003120206926088,481079011095061871685.93693360151844571234
8,9,28,37,38,.00000006712696134888,478947183738005855802.00670201343590077565
8,27,28,37,38,.00000006760193942443,478231137920953501587.46466433784148271390
9,21,27,28,49,.00000004381964503040,477284627782535041437.11297160028593654028
7,9,21,27,28,.00000007343440922844,469911494200724179611.21320224196959249553
9,27,28,29,49,.00000003526655803038,467904373393879427639.03524344357786389758
6,9,27,28,49,.00000004525984628343,467690753220418167446.88473155114670318971
7,9,27,28,29,.00000005910086338412,460676146780810152696.99944525511300839499
6,7,9,27,28,.00000007584794608191,460465826629983226941.93084428564568750982
9,27,28,31,37,.00000006811103364324,459496996558773363769.05382757323633883513
8,9,22,27,37,.00000003404541820778,456747510194405716766.20695671516633183801
8,9,27,37,40,.00000003040697656726,456747510194405713264.47604522472668474869
8,9,27,28,31,.00000006086172977889,455560565803478399282.82240491410563855330
8,9,28,36,37,.00000002876724297450,455125550419553196042.14370655612878221285
8,27,28,36,37,.00000002897079471336,454445118927988480071.15879710827294996539
9,21,27,37,49,.00000004270303063827,453145035152364493764.22369236831715865305
8,9,21,27,49,.00000003815799250764,449263020544343383973.74189948192262048935
6,9,21,27,29,.00000005859174733335,449032622060132765603.33487380932941207583
8,9,28,37,46,.00000004312324492792,448978003798105522076.50929286694923319877
8,27,28,37,46,.00000004342837710545,448306763142593054164.31696119829074720829
9,27,28,38,49,.00000004721267064345,447692638637972009362.46827979134118950117
7,9,21,27,37,.00000007156314992990,446144812053549198717.17483369028309441043
9,27,29,37,49,.00000003436789383011,444239205261228390891.39536705114368980098
6,9,27,37,49,.00000004410653261075,444036389340962753703.93526391684813155733
7,8,9,21,27,.00000006394642483293,442322767137836136294.10504260814917115230
7,9,27,28,38,.00000007912055367847,440776644624908730133.00186293320269407438
8,9,27,29,49,.00000003070999448216,440433485347073485038.79524946280933301948
```

Actual result of the script:

```
Number 6: found in 24 combinaisons. Must be part in: 3 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 7: found in 9 combinaisons. Must be part in: 1 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 8: found in 50 combinaisons. Must be part in: 7 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 9: found in 94 combinaisons. Must be part in: 13 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 21: found in 27 combinaisons. Must be part in: 3 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 22: found in 3 combinaisons. Must be part in: 0 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 27: found in 94 combinaisons. Must be part in: 13 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 28: found in 56 combinaisons. Must be part in: 7 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 29: found in 22 combinaisons. Must be part in: 3 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 31: found in 2 combinaisons. Must be part in: 0 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 36: found in 14 combinaisons. Must be part in: 1 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 37: found in 51 combinaisons. Must be part in: 7 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 38: found in 22 combinaisons. Must be part in: 3 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 40: found in 3 combinaisons. Must be part in: 0 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 46: found in 17 combinaisons. Must be part in: 2 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 49: found in 12 combinaisons. Must be part in: 1 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.

Among the 100 combinations submitted, 16 different numbers have been identified.
```

So we identified 16 unique numbers, but 3 of them (40, 31 & 22) have a rounded frequency equal to 0. This means that they are not frequent enough in the 100 combinations to be representative of the original data in a sample of 14 most representative combinations of the set.

Regarding the remaining 13 numbers, the script indicates that they must respectively appear in:
Number 6: 3 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 7: 1 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 9: 13 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
... etc

So a desired script's output exemple (Here I sort them myself with my brain and choose 14 of them trying to keep proportions. I don't manage: nums 21, 36 & 49 appears one more time than they should. Sometimes it can't be perfect. But I want to be as close as possible to the expected proportions) could be:

```
Number 6: found in 24 combinaisons. Must be part in: 3 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 7: found in 9 combinaisons. Must be part in: 1 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 8: found in 50 combinaisons. Must be part in: 7 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 9: found in 94 combinaisons. Must be part in: 13 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 21: found in 27 combinaisons. Must be part in: 3 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 22: found in 3 combinaisons. Must be part in: 0 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 27: found in 94 combinaisons. Must be part in: 13 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 28: found in 56 combinaisons. Must be part in: 7 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 29: found in 22 combinaisons. Must be part in: 3 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 31: found in 2 combinaisons. Must be part in: 0 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 36: found in 14 combinaisons. Must be part in: 1 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 37: found in 51 combinaisons. Must be part in: 7 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 38: found in 22 combinaisons. Must be part in: 3 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 40: found in 3 combinaisons. Must be part in: 0 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 46: found in 17 combinaisons. Must be part in: 2 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 49: found in 12 combinaisons. Must be part in: 1 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.

Among the 100 combinations submitted, 16 different numbers have been identified.
Here is an equiproportional selection (14 combinations) in terms of frequency of appearance of all the numbers found in the list :
7,9,21,27,28
6,9,27,28,37
6,9,27,37,38
6,9,21,27,29
8,9,27,28,49
8,9,27,37,49
8,27,28,37,46
8,9,27,29,46
8,9,28,36,37
8,9,27,36,38
8,9,27,28,37
9,21,27,37,38
9,21,27,28,29
9,27,28,29,46
```

**EDIT:** Thank you very much for your contributions. The closest thing to the expected result is the code that follows below. However, the code is horrible, and the computation time monstrous. Could you help me reduce this time? I don't manage to use coproc in the infinite loop calculations.

Output (infinite loop until perfect result found):

```
Number 6: found in 24 combinaisons. Must be part in: 3 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 7: found in 9 combinaisons. Must be part in: 1 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 8: found in 50 combinaisons. Must be part in: 7 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 9: found in 94 combinaisons. Must be part in: 13 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 21: found in 27 combinaisons. Must be part in: 3 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 22: found in 3 combinaisons. Must be part in: 0 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 27: found in 94 combinaisons. Must be part in: 13 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 28: found in 56 combinaisons. Must be part in: 7 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 29: found in 22 combinaisons. Must be part in: 3 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 31: found in 2 combinaisons. Must be part in: 0 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 36: found in 14 combinaisons. Must be part in: 1 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 37: found in 51 combinaisons. Must be part in: 7 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 38: found in 22 combinaisons. Must be part in: 3 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 40: found in 3 combinaisons. Must be part in: 0 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 46: found in 17 combinaisons. Must be part in: 2 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 49: found in 12 combinaisons. Must be part in: 1 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.

Among the 100 combinations submitted, 16 different numbers have been identified.
Now we'll try to make an equiproportional selection (14 combinations) in terms of frequency of appearance of all the numbers found in the list. Press Enter to start ...

The 14 random combinations we picked up:
6 8 27 28 37 9 21 27 28 49 7 8 9 27 37 8 9 27 28 31 8 9 28 29 37 8 21 27 28 37 8 9 27 29 49 8 9 21 27 49 8 9 27 37 40 9 27 28 31 37 9 21 27 28 37 6 9 27 28 38 8 9 27 29 37 7 9 27 28 38
How many times the number was found in these combinations:
0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 9 12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 13 9 3 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 8 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3
How many times we want it in these combinations:
0 0 0 0 0 0 3 1 7 13 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 13 7 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 7 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 1
Perfect equi-proportionality: no
Gap: 18
Current best gap: 10

Here is the best equiproportional selection (14 combinations) in terms of frequency of appearance of all the numbers found in the list for now (84 trials) :
9 27 28 29 37
8 27 28 37 38
6 9 27 28 36
8 9 27 36 38
6 9 27 28 37
8 9 21 27 36
9 27 28 36 37
8 9 21 27 37
9 21 27 28 29
9 21 27 28 36
6 8 9 27 38
9 27 29 37 46
6 9 27 37 49
6 8 9 27 46
```

The script (sorry for your eyes):

```
#!/bin/bash
#Either a list of 100 combinations composed of 5 numbers ranging from 1 to 49. The purpose of this script is to choose 14 of these combinations in an equiporportional way, i.e. by including all the numbers found in the list, and by taking into account their frequency of occurrence.

numbers=() #table to store numbers
freqs=() #table to store freqs
random_combs=() #table to store the 14 randomly picked up combis
numbers_found=() #table to store num
for (( i=1; i<=50; i++ )); do
 numbers+=(0) #for each number (from 1 to 49), its number of occurrences is initialized to zero.
 freqs+=(0)
 numbers_found+=(0)
done
coproc bc -l 2>&1
while IFS=',' read -r num_1 num_2 num_3 num_4 num_5 p p1 pd; do #Loop to count the frequency of appearance of numbers in each combination (use coproc for faster computing in case we have more than 100 combinaisons in future)
  echo "${numbers[$num_1]} + 1" >&${COPROC[1]}
  read numbers[num_1] <&${COPROC[0]}
  echo "${numbers[$num_2]} + 1" >&${COPROC[1]}
  read numbers[num_2] <&${COPROC[0]}
  echo "${numbers[$num_3]} + 1" >&${COPROC[1]}
  read numbers[num_3] <&${COPROC[0]}
  echo "${numbers[$num_4]} + 1" >&${COPROC[1]}
  read numbers[num_4] <&${COPROC[0]}
  echo "${numbers[$num_5]} + 1" >&${COPROC[1]}
  read numbers[num_5] <&${COPROC[0]}
done < ./tmp
count_numbers=0 #variable to store the number of unique numbers found
for (( i=1; i<=49; i++ )); do
  if [ ${numbers[$i]} -gt 0 ]; then #If the number has been found in at least one combination, it is counted
    echo "Number $i: found in ${numbers[$i]} combinaisons. Must be part in: $(echo "scale=0; $(bc -l <<< "scale=10; $(echo "14/100*${numbers[$i]}" | bc -l)")/1" | bc -l) of the 14 combinations that will be picked up." #The number is displayed on the screen, the number of times it has been found in the list of combinations, as well as its frequency of appearance rounded to the nearest integer (knowing this frequency allows you to know how many of the 14 combinations will contain the number).
    freqs[$i]=$(echo "scale=0; $(bc -l <<< "scale=10; $(echo "14/100*${numbers[$i]}" | bc -l)")/1" | bc -l)
    count_numbers=$((count_numbers+1))
  fi
done
echo
echo "Among the 100 combinations submitted, $count_numbers different numbers have been identified."
echo "Now we'll try to make an equiproportional selection (14 combinations) in terms of frequency of appearance of all the numbers found in the list. Press Enter to start ..."
read
best_ecart=1000 #we initialize to a value greater than the maximum gap that there may be
best_combs=() #we will store the best result found for the moment
count_try=0 #we count the attempts
while true; do
  random_combs=() #table to store the 14 randomly picked up combis
  numbers_found=() #array to store the numbers found in these combinations
  for (( i=1; i<=50; i++ )); do
    numbers_found+=(0)
  done
  readarray -t random_lines <<< "$(shuf -i 1-100 -n 14)" #we choose 14 numbers of lines out of 100 randomly
  for (( i=0; i<=13; i++ )); do
    read -r -a colonnes <<< "$(sed -n "${random_lines[i]}p" tmp | awk -F ',' '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}')" #recovery of 14 lines
    random_combs+=("${colonnes[@]}")
  done
  for (( i=0; i<=69; i++ )); do
    numbers_found[${random_combs[$i]}]=$(echo "${numbers_found[${random_combs[$i]}]}+1" | bc) #we count the number of occurrences of each number
  done
  clear
  echo "The 14 random combinations we picked up:"
  echo "${random_combs[@]}"
  echo "How many times the number was found in these combinations:"
  echo "${numbers_found[@]}"
  echo "How many times we want it in these combinations:"
  echo "${freqs[@]}"
  if [ "${numbers_found[*]}" == "${freqs[*]}" ]; then #if we find a set of 14 perfectly equiproportional combinations
    echo "Perfect equi-proportionality: YES"
    nb_elements=5
    # nombre de tours
    nb_tours=14

    # boucle for
    for (( i=0; i<nb_tours; i++ )); do
      start=$((i*nb_elements))
      end=$((start+nb_elements-1))
      echo "${random_combs[@]:$start:$nb_elements}" #display these 14 combinations
    done
    exit 1
  else #If we don't have equi-proportionality
    echo "Perfect equi-proportionality: no"
    ecart_total=0
    for (( i=0; i<=69; i++ )); do
      ecart=$((freqs[i]-numbers_found[i]))
      if (( $ecart < 0 )); then
        ecart=$(( $ecart * -1 ))
      fi
    ecart_total=$((ecart_total+ecart)) #calculation of the deviation of the sample of combinations from the expected proportions
    done
    echo "Gap: $ecart_total" #Display current deviation
    echo "Current best gap: $best_ecart" #Display best deviation we found from the begenning
    if (( $ecart_total < $best_ecart )); then #check if the current deviation is better than the best we know
      best_ecart=$((ecart_total))
      best_combs=("${random_combs[@]}")
    fi
  fi
  count_try=$((count_try+1)) # count each comparaison
  echo ""
  echo "Here is the best equiproportional selection (14 combinations) in terms of frequency of appearance of all the numbers found in the list for now ($count_try trials) :"
  nb_elements=5
  # nombre de tours
  nb_tours=14
  # boucle for
  for (( i=0; i<nb_tours; i++ )); do
    start=$((i*nb_elements))
    end=$((start+nb_elements-1))
    echo "${best_combs[@]:$start:$nb_elements}" #Showing the best sample of 14 combinations found so far
  done
done
```

Comment: Can you provide the content of `./tmp` file and the expected output?

Comment: Please edit question and add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: What is to prevent duplicate numbers in `./tmp` causing you to overwrite, e.g. `numbers[$num_1]` if `$num_1` is duplicated?

Comment: @David C. Rankin, not sure I understand your question but in a combination a number can't be found more than once.
Also, even if numbers can go from 1 to 49, normally there is less than 20 diff numbers in the 100 combinations because these combinations have many numbers in common.
If the case where there is too much different numbers to fit in 14 combinations, we choose to skip some numbers (them with the lowest frequency).

Comment: @Cyrus, sorry should have do it before. done.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Let me understand about the logic to pick the 14 combinations.
Do we need to make the result include all 16 numbers? Then how about `31` which appear
just 2 times in the `tmp` file but not found in the shown expected output?
Or do we need to make the occurence probability as close as the `tmp` file, e.g.
`9` and `27` which occur highest 94 times in `tmp` should be included as propotionally many times so that the picked 14 combinations well represent the original data?

Comment: I'm confused about your *"choose 14 of them trying to keep proportions"*? You don't need to initialize the array to `0` and you don't need `bc` in your read loop bash `((numbers[num_1]++))` is fine. Computing the occurrences (which is the percent since there are 100 records) and sorting by the occurrence with `sort` is simple enough `8, 37, 28, 9, 27` are the five most frequently occurring numbers `50, 51, 56, 94, 94` times each, respectively -- then what?

Comment: Since I'm unclear where you are going, here is a link to updates to your code that produces the ordered list of indexes [NumberCombinations](https://paste.opensuse.org/pastes/d9a73ee17ec0) I'll check back tomorrow.

Comment: @tshiono, thanks for your reply.
Q:Do we need to make the result include all 16 numbers?
A:Yes. In this case it is possible (only 16 diff numbers). But, f the case happen where there is too much different numbers to fit in 14 combinations, we choose to skip some numbers (them with the lowest frequency).

Comment: @tshiono,
Q:Then how about 31 which appear just 2 times in the tmp file but not found in the shown expected output?
A:There is also some cases where a number can be find in the list, but it's rounded frequency is zero, so we do not keep it. This is the case with number 31 (but also with n°40 et n°22): is skipped because its frequency of appearance rounded to the nearest integer: 14/100*${numbers[$i]} = 14/100*2 = .28000000000000000000 =~ 0
So Note that numbers less than 0.5 are rounded to Zero so they will not be selected to be in the final list.

Comment: @tshiono,
Q:Or do we need to make the occurence probability as close as the tmp file, e.g. 9 and 27 which occur highest 94 times in tmp should be included as propotionally many times so that the picked 14 combinations well represent the original data? 
A:Exactly, all numbers wich are not skipped due to frequency less than 0.5 should be included as propotionally many times so that the picked 14 combinations well represent the original data.

Comment: @David C. Rankin, thank you a lot, this code do the same things but in a far better way than mine. I tried to clarify the intended purpose in the replies to [at]tshiono

Comment: I modified my post with a concrete example to try to be as clear as possible regarding the logic of the expected result. Thank you in advance for your contributions in solving this.

Comment: Okay, now the logic on what you are waning to end up with is clear. I'll have time in a couple of hours to think though logic to get there. `awk` would likely provide a better solution (it does whenever you are dealing with records (lines) of data and fields.

Comment: My thought on getting the number frequency to include in your 5-number sets would be a modification of your logic, e.g. `$(((1400 * ${numbers[i]}) / 10000))`. That shows which numbers must occur 1 to 13 times in the answer you give (how you get there can be done many ways). To see the result, change the `for` loop contents to `printf "\nindex occurs freq\n----- ------ ----\n"` and then `printf "%3d   %3d   %3d\n" "$i" "${numbers[i]}" $(((1400 * ${numbers[i]}) / 10000))` in the link I gave. Idea, use result to create 5 element array with required no. and randoms, then shuffle array.

Comment: @David C. Rankin, thank you. I just post the code I added to the script. The code is very bad I guess, but matches what I'm looking to achieve. I am looking to reduce the calculation time wich is horrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks like a variant of `a knapsack problem`.
In order to calculate the strict (optimized) answer, we will need to
examine over the all possible combinations of C(100, 14) (= 44186942677323600).
A practical alternative will be to pick 14 samples randomly out of the 100
items in the list and minimize the error (difference to the original probabilities of
occurrence) with repetitions. The result may not be optimized but will give
an approximation depending on the number of repetitions.
The outline of the process is:

0. read the original list and calculate the probabilities of each number.
1. generate 14 random numbers between 1 and 100 inclusive. The number
   indexes the serial number in the original list.
2. split the indexed line into 5 numbers and accumulate the frequency of
   the number.
3. compare the probabilities between the picked 14 samples with the original
   list. The used criteria is a "gap" to sum the deviations from the expected occurrences.
4. compare the gap with the minimum gap in the loop.
   If the current gap is smaller (=better) than the previous one,
   then update with it.
5. report current status.
6. go to 1. for an infinite loop.

Here's an awk script:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -F, '
#
# generate n random numbers out of integers between 1 and m (inclusive)
# return a comma separated string
#
function random(m, n,   i, r, a, d, x) {
    for (i = 1; i <= n; ) {
        r = int(rand() * m) + 1
        if (! (r in a)) {
            a[r]
            x = x d r
            d = ","
            i++
        }
    }
    return x
}
#
# calculate the gap between theoretically expected frequency and the frequency of the picked set of 14 samples
#
function calc_gap(a, b,   i, diff, gap) {
    for (i in a) {
        diff = a[i] - b[i]
        if (diff < 0) diff = - diff
        gap += diff
    }
    return gap
}

{
    # loop over input "tmp" file
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) numbers[$i]++      # count the occurrences
    a[++n] = sprintf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5)
}

END {
    best_ecart = -1                             # negative value denotes "unset"

    for (i in numbers) {
        freqs[i] = int(numbers[i] * 14 / n + 0.5)     # expected frequency in the picked result
        printf("Number %2d: found in %2d combinations. Must be part in %2d of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.\n", i, numbers[i], freqs[i])
        count_numbers++
    }

    printf("Among the %d combinations submitted, %d different numbers have been identified.\n", n, count_numbers)
    print("Now we will try to make an equiproportional selection (14 combinations) in terms of frequency of appearance of all the numbers found in the list. Press Enter to start ...")
    getline i < "-"

    for (i = 1; ; i++) {                        # infinite loop
        system("clear")
        print("The 14 random combinations we picked up:")
        delete numbers_found
        split(random(n, 14), b, ",")            # pick 14 combinations randomly
        for (j in b) {                          # j is the index between 1 and n (=100)
            split(a[b[j]], c, ",")              # dereference numbers between 1 and 49
            for (k in c) {
                printf("%d ", c[k]);
                numbers_found[c[k]]++           # count the occurrences of the number
            }
        }
        print("")
        print("How many times the number was found in these combinations:")
        for (j = 1; j <= 49; j++) {
            printf("%d ", numbers_found[j])
        }
        print("")
        print("How many times we want it in these combinations:")
        for (j = 1; j <= 49; j++) {
            printf("%d ", freqs[j])
        }
        print("")
        gap = calc_gap(freqs, numbers_found)    # calculate the gap
        if (best_ecart < 0 || gap < best_ecart) {
                                                # update the minimum error condition
            delete combo
            for (j in b) combo[j] = b[j]        # copy array b to array combo
            best_ecart = gap
        }

        printf("Gap: %d\n", gap)
        printf("Current best gap: %d\n", best_ecart)
        print("")

        printf("Here is an equiproportional selection (14 combinations) in terms of frequency of appearance of all the numbers found in the list for now (%d trials) :\n", i)

        for (j in combo) {
            print(a[combo[j]])
            split(a[combo[j]], d, ",")
            for (k in d) p3[d[k]]++             # count (again) the occurrences of the final result
        }
    }
#   for (i in freqs) {
#       printf("%d: freq: %2d (expected: %2d)\n", i, p3[i], freqs[i])
#   }
}' ./tmp
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I edited my original post with the code I added to the original script. The code is very bad I guess, but better matches what I'm looking to achieve. I am looking to reduce the calculation time of my script

Comment: Although you have solved it for yourself, I've updated my answer with some modifications: 1) to apply the same criteria as yours to calculate `gap`, the deviations from the expected frequencies. 2) to fix the mistakes in variable initialization which caused insufficient accuracy. 3) to report current result on the fly as yours. The code will run much faster than bash. FYI.

Comment: There is an error, but this script does exactly the same thing as mine but much  (very) faster. And the code is much cleaner.

Could you edit your reply (line #42 of the code) to round to the nearest integer instead of the lower integer: int(numbers[i] * 14 / n + 0.5)

Once done I'll mark your answer as the solution since it does over 200,000 comparisons in minutes, while mine does around 50,000 an hour. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've fixed the rounding accordingly.  BTW desite your modesty, I'd appreciate your code as an excellent one especially for its correctness and the technnique in bash array and `shuf` command. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you also for the compliment and for the script.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution that comes closest to the result I wanted to obtain.

The code is not very clean because I never really learned to code in a professional way, and in addition I have a lot of trouble with abstract reasoning. I need a fairly trivial syntax to find my way around.

In the end, even if my code looks more like a child's scribbling than a master painting, even if it is not at all optimized in terms of resources/calculation time, what matters to me is the result.

The solution is quite simplistic, it consists of a perpetual loop during which 14 combinations are randomly chosen from the 100, we count how many times each number appears in the list, and we save the result if the difference is less than the best difference previously found.

The program only stops if a perfect result is found, ie if 3 conditions are met: deviation from zero + 100% of the numbers present in the original set are in the sample (except those excluded due to a frequency of occurrence < 0.5, and therefore rounded to zero) + 100% of the numbers present in the sample are in the original set. The best result I have obtained so far is a gap of 2 (which is very satisfactory for the destination application).

SCRIPT:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Either a list of 100 combinations composed of 5 numbers ranging from 1 to 49. The purpose of this script is to choose 14 of these combinations in an equiporportional way, i.e. by including all the numbers found in the list, and by taking into account their frequency of occurrence.
clear
numbers=() #table to store numbers
freqs=() #table to store freqs
random_combs=() #table to store the 14 randomly picked up combis
numbers_found=() #table to store num
for (( i=1; i<=50; i++ )); do
 numbers+=(0) #for each number (from 1 to 49), its number of occurrences is initialized to zero.
 freqs+=(0)
 numbers_found+=(0)
done
coproc bc -l 2>&1
while IFS=',' read -r num_1 num_2 num_3 num_4 num_5 p p1 pd; do #Loop to count the frequency of appearance of numbers in each combination (use coproc for faster computing in case we have more than 100 combinaisons in future)
  echo "${numbers[$num_1]} + 1" >&${COPROC[1]}
  read numbers[num_1] <&${COPROC[0]}
  echo "${numbers[$num_2]} + 1" >&${COPROC[1]}
  read numbers[num_2] <&${COPROC[0]}
  echo "${numbers[$num_3]} + 1" >&${COPROC[1]}
  read numbers[num_3] <&${COPROC[0]}
  echo "${numbers[$num_4]} + 1" >&${COPROC[1]}
  read numbers[num_4] <&${COPROC[0]}
  echo "${numbers[$num_5]} + 1" >&${COPROC[1]}
  read numbers[num_5] <&${COPROC[0]}
done < ./tmp
count_numbers=0 #variable to store the number of unique numbers found
for (( i=1; i<=49; i++ )); do
  if [ ${numbers[$i]} -gt 0 ]; then #If the number has been found in at least one combination, it is counted
    echo "Number $i: found in ${numbers[$i]} combinaisons. Must be part in: $(echo "scale=0; $(echo "(14/100*${numbers[$i]})+0.5" | bc -l)/1" | bc -l) of the 14 combinations that will be picked up." #The number is displayed on the screen, the number of times it has been found in the list of combinations, as well as its frequency of appearance rounded to the nearest integer (knowing this frequency allows you to know how many of the 14 combinations will contain the number).
    freqs[$i]=$(echo "scale=0; $(echo "(14/100*${numbers[$i]})+0.5" | bc -l)/1" | bc -l)
    count_numbers=$((count_numbers+1))
  fi
done
echo
echo "Among the 100 combinations submitted, $count_numbers different numbers have been identified."
echo "Now we'll try to make an equiproportional selection (14 combinations) in terms of frequency of appearance of all the numbers found in the list. Press Enter to start ..."
read
best_ecart=1000 #we initialize to a value greater than the maximum gap that there may be
best_combs=() #we will store the best result found for the moment
count_try=0 #we count the attempts
while true; do
  random_combs=() #table to store the 14 randomly picked up combis
  numbers_found=() #array to store the numbers found in these combinations
  for (( i=1; i<=50; i++ )); do
    numbers_found+=(0)
  done
  readarray -t random_lines <<< "$(shuf -i 1-100 -n 14)" #we choose 14 numbers of lines out of 100 randomly
  for (( i=0; i<=13; i++ )); do
    read -r -a colonnes <<< "$(sed -n "${random_lines[i]}p" tmp | awk -F ',' '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}')" #recovery of 14 lines
    random_combs+=("${colonnes[@]}")
  done
  for (( i=0; i<=69; i++ )); do
    numbers_found[${random_combs[$i]}]=$(echo "${numbers_found[${random_combs[$i]}]}+1" | bc) #we count the number of occurrences of each number
  done
  clear
  echo "The 14 random combinations we picked up:"
  echo "${random_combs[@]}"
  echo "How many times the number was found in these combinations:"
  echo "${numbers_found[@]}"
  echo "How many times we want it in these combinations:"
  echo "${freqs[@]}"
  if [ "${numbers_found[*]}" == "${freqs[*]}" ]; then #if we find a set of 14 perfectly equiproportional combinations
    echo "Perfect equi-proportionality: YES"
    nb_elements=5
    # nombre de tours
    nb_tours=14

    # boucle for
    for (( i=0; i<nb_tours; i++ )); do
      start=$((i*nb_elements))
      end=$((start+nb_elements-1))
      echo "${random_combs[@]:$start:$nb_elements}" #display these 14 combinations
    done
    exit 1
  else #If we don't have equi-proportionality
    echo "Perfect equi-proportionality: no"
    ecart_total=0
    for (( i=0; i<=69; i++ )); do
      ecart=$((freqs[i]-numbers_found[i]))
      if (( $ecart < 0 )); then
        ecart=$(( $ecart * -1 ))
      fi
    ecart_total=$((ecart_total+ecart)) #calculation of the deviation of the sample of combinations from the expected proportions
    done
    echo "Gap: $ecart_total" #Display current deviation
    echo "Current best gap: $best_ecart" #Display best deviation we found from the begenning
    if (( $ecart_total < $best_ecart )); then #check if the current deviation is better than the best we know
      best_ecart=$((ecart_total))
      best_combs=("${random_combs[@]}")
      best_nums=("${numbers_found[@]}")
    fi
  fi
  count_try=$((count_try+1)) # count each comparaison
  echo ""
  echo "Here is the best equiproportional selection (14 combinations) in terms of frequency of appearance of all the numbers found in the list for now ($count_try trials) :"
  echo "How many times the number was found in these combinations:"
  echo "${best_nums[@]}"
  echo ""
  nb_elements=5
  # nombre de tours
  nb_tours=14
  # boucle for
  for (( i=0; i<nb_tours; i++ )); do
    start=$((i*nb_elements))
    end=$((start+nb_elements-1))
    echo "${best_combs[@]:$start:$nb_elements}" #Showing the best sample of 14 combinations found so far
  done
function clean_up {
count_numbers=0 #variable to store the number of unique numbers found
for (( i=1; i<=49; i++ )); do
  if [ ${numbers[$i]} -gt 0 ]; then #If the number has been found in at least one combination, it is counted
    echo "Number $i: found in ${numbers[$i]} combinations. Should have to be part in: $(echo "scale=0; $(echo "(14/100*${numbers[$i]})+0.5" | bc -l)/1" | bc -l) of the 14 combinations. Is in: ${best_nums[$i]} of the 14 picked up combinations." #The number is displayed on the screen, the number of times it has been found in the list of combinations, as well as its frequency of appearance rounded to the nearest integer (knowing this frequency allows you to know how many of the 14 combinations will contain the number).
    freqs[$i]=$(echo "scale=0; $(echo "(14/100*${numbers[$i]})+0.5" | bc -l)/1" | bc -l)
    count_numbers=$((count_numbers+1))
  fi
done
    echo "Signal SIGINT reçu. Arrêt en cours..."
    exit 1
}
trap clean_up SIGINT
done
```

OUTPUT 1:

```
Number 6: found in 31 combinaisons. Must be part in: 4 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 7: found in 16 combinaisons. Must be part in: 2 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 8: found in 48 combinaisons. Must be part in: 7 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 10: found in 1 combinaisons. Must be part in: 0 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 21: found in 34 combinaisons. Must be part in: 5 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 22: found in 10 combinaisons. Must be part in: 1 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 27: found in 90 combinaisons. Must be part in: 13 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 28: found in 67 combinaisons. Must be part in: 9 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 29: found in 30 combinaisons. Must be part in: 4 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 31: found in 3 combinaisons. Must be part in: 0 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 32: found in 1 combinaisons. Must be part in: 0 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 36: found in 64 combinaisons. Must be part in: 9 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 37: found in 58 combinaisons. Must be part in: 8 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 38: found in 31 combinaisons. Must be part in: 4 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 40: found in 10 combinaisons. Must be part in: 1 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 46: found in 5 combinaisons. Must be part in: 1 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.
Number 49: found in 1 combinaisons. Must be part in: 0 of the 14 combinations that will be picked up.

Among the 100 combinations submitted, 17 different numbers have been identified.
Now we'll try to make an equiproportional selection (14 combinations) in terms of frequency of appearance of all the numbers found in the list. Press Enter to start ...
```

OUTPUT 2:

```
The 14 random combinations we picked up:
8 27 28 37 40 8 27 28 36 37 21 27 28 36 38 8 27 28 29 38 7 8 27 28 37 6 8 27 28 29 7 21 27 36 37 8 22 27 28 37 27 28 29 36 37 6 8 21 28 36 8 27 31 36 37 8 21 27 36 38 6 8 21 27 28 27 28 29 36 38
How many times the number was found in these combinations:
0 0 0 0 0 0 3 2 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 1 0 0 0 0 13 11 4 0 1 0 0 0 0 8 7 4 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
How many times we want it in these combinations:
0 0 0 0 0 0 4 2 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 1 0 0 0 0 13 9 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 8 4 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
Perfect equi-proportionality: no
Gap: 10
Current best gap: 2

Here is the best equiproportional selection (14 combinations) in terms of frequency of appearance of all the numbers found in the list for now (69803 trials) :
How many times the number was found in these combinations:
0 0 0 0 0 0 4 2 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 1 0 0 0 0 13 9 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 8 4 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0

27 28 29 36 38
6 8 21 28 36
21 27 28 36 37
27 36 37 38 46
7 21 27 36 37
8 27 29 36 38
27 28 29 36 37
6 7 8 27 36
6 8 21 27 36
27 28 37 38 40
8 27 28 37 40
8 21 27 28 29
6 22 27 28 37
8 27 28 29 37
^CNumber 6: found in 31 combinaisons. Should have to be part in: 4 of the 14 combinations. Is in: 4 of the 14 picked up combinations.
Number 7: found in 16 combinaisons. Should have to be part in: 2 of the 14 combinations. Is in: 2 of the 14 picked up combinations.
Number 8: found in 48 combinaisons. Should have to be part in: 7 of the 14 combinations. Is in: 7 of the 14 picked up combinations.
Number 10: found in 1 combinaisons. Should have to be part in: 0 of the 14 combinations. Is in: 0 of the 14 picked up combinations.
Number 21: found in 34 combinaisons. Should have to be part in: 5 of the 14 combinations. Is in: 5 of the 14 picked up combinations.
Number 22: found in 10 combinaisons. Should have to be part in: 1 of the 14 combinations. Is in: 1 of the 14 picked up combinations.
Number 27: found in 90 combinaisons. Should have to be part in: 13 of the 14 combinations. Is in: 13 of the 14 picked up combinations.
Number 28: found in 67 combinaisons. Should have to be part in: 9 of the 14 combinations. Is in: 9 of the 14 picked up combinations.
Number 29: found in 30 combinaisons. Should have to be part in: 4 of the 14 combinations. Is in: 5 of the 14 picked up combinations.
Number 31: found in 3 combinaisons. Should have to be part in: 0 of the 14 combinations. Is in: 0 of the 14 picked up combinations.
Number 32: found in 1 combinaisons. Should have to be part in: 0 of the 14 combinations. Is in: 0 of the 14 picked up combinations.
Number 36: found in 64 combinaisons. Should have to be part in: 9 of the 14 combinations. Is in: 9 of the 14 picked up combinations.
Number 37: found in 58 combinaisons. Should have to be part in: 8 of the 14 combinations. Is in: 8 of the 14 picked up combinations.
Number 38: found in 31 combinaisons. Should have to be part in: 4 of the 14 combinations. Is in: 4 of the 14 picked up combinations.
Number 40: found in 10 combinaisons. Should have to be part in: 1 of the 14 combinations. Is in: 2 of the 14 picked up combinations.
Number 46: found in 5 combinaisons. Should have to be part in: 1 of the 14 combinations. Is in: 1 of the 14 picked up combinations.
Number 49: found in 1 combinaisons. Should have to be part in: 0 of the 14 combinations. Is in: 0 of the 14 picked up combinations.
Signal SIGINT reçu. Arrêt en cours...
```

Content of tmp file:

```
8,27,28,36,37,.00000003363295598992,1057466439609455967613.47746514026993887119
27,28,29,36,37,.00000003091260355176,839943666229817676309.34037540948743602835
21,27,28,36,37,.00000003694859659461,824189514992559971573.47115616661613915867
8,21,27,28,36,.00000003304833727621,817928570328955147713.07370961288803230573
6,27,28,36,37,.00000003824894930748,809442054925597441413.52666521719987836631
6,8,27,28,36,.00000003421142597223,803293139145797095203.70205480150117560452
8,21,27,36,37,.00000003239176058682,781034565030950634935.06100020114508104015
27,28,36,37,38,.00000004009858596371,778701461611639000691.51302533009025993286
8,27,28,36,38,.00000003586581671200,772786066339154037233.33479587458596794083
6,8,27,36,37,.00000003353174201064,767059288897019988973.39318331464231486848
8,27,36,37,38,.00000003515326470062,737928287481674862907.06407700532975055840
21,27,28,29,36,.00000003037527086738,649679173109213923331.14745913609417283397
6,27,28,29,36,.00000003144428483589,638054276786853090157.38824871765373722638
6,21,27,28,36,.00000003758409393315,626086803278541839276.37238341102501426122
21,27,29,36,37,.00000002977180042290,620374331923565461244.84414452233013283211
7,27,28,36,37,.00000003732739891602,616153026002399361399.25062798752795757062
27,28,29,36,38,.00000003296486260115,613822564441811391111.10606025287017588421
7,8,27,28,36,.00000003338715357866,611472427754132986174.17445609991225750674
6,27,29,36,37,.00000003081957611711,609273795553973416731.73657610809879769434
21,27,28,36,38,.00000003940157961807,602309585772106446734.08259557499748139661
6,21,27,36,37,.00000003683740462887,597846134502441600584.40569055608823359101
6,8,21,27,36,.00000003294888263044,593304604311410692085.47240959645063804972
6,27,28,36,38,.00000004078826154025,591532287101662833834.79612879462424579035
27,29,36,37,38,.00000003230994431670,586135094207774971749.77481724369871987776
7,8,27,36,37,.00000003272384557071,583890964277350900324.68970046384974891922
8,27,29,36,38,.00000002889933679672,581682526778225951213.57957998394618588066
21,27,36,37,38,.00000003861878203022,575141427262155025370.79388441689322362284
8,21,27,36,38,.00000003454221949847,570772373077004958679.36440793351329908096
6,27,36,37,38,.00000003997791451722,564850256266754735032.86306053984533910502
6,8,27,36,38,.00000003575788323060,560559378824882547787.73027550235489257569
27,28,36,38,46,.00000002881864368357,559648661385979856768.04348131529288622260
27,36,37,38,46,.00000002824609900441,534404793611693200837.52952720143135798632
8,27,28,29,37,.00000005361696082981,531868236999183922703.90570193037867082226
8,27,28,37,40,.00000003421787696366,528733219804727983718.61652926934697720991
8,22,27,28,37,.00000003831232377982,528733219804727979753.11738073298850354279
8,21,27,28,37,.00000006408620525969,521892410070707334570.54481530044415648136
8,21,28,36,37,.00000003118993096012,519040037806435198915.44751913585561026111
6,8,27,28,37,.00000006634162707669,512554039056805185941.60452252703466452151
6,8,28,36,37,.00000003228761571885,509752705109932470920.90259204374957438975
8,27,28,37,38,.00000006954976501241,493088513179822800469.14805992018832120064
8,28,36,37,38,.00000003384897514589,490393566919472391301.38648094338962784981
7,27,28,29,36,.00000003068668250892,485691435234519284750.11021931882037829360
8,27,28,37,46,.00000004687318458583,484927345642621152444.07185601574768907017
7,21,27,28,36,.00000003667856222302,476581709626764305219.91620915662870726416
27,28,31,36,37,.00000003454311550292,473189735735763775948.56711214437339147391
6,21,27,29,36,.00000003028386046512,471260766176566006111.47904275469630838979
8,27,28,31,36,.00000003089677652001,469595156216204913773.30729806370395221807
6,7,27,28,36,.00000003796941146458,468054096009368450862.05447422677712347054
7,27,29,36,37,.00000003007702519873,463783529049592828804.77384205948622608943
7,21,27,36,37,.00000003594986326445,455084712507773410056.32488123943888678331
21,27,29,36,38,.00000003174832261173,453363455961828175828.17162031070526170012
7,8,21,27,36,.00000003215502930280,451627667555813059919.89040653816128254890
7,27,28,36,38,.00000003980553027391,450278567141302661753.95473753592832494855
8,27,31,36,37,.00000003028294523795,448413299010275501214.83885468533104240209
6,7,27,36,37,.00000003721506699427,446941750843362893817.72826320963914818682
6,27,29,36,38,.00000003286565916148,445251293235907619359.50435055580369835470
6,7,8,27,36,.00000003328667930957,443546563791134732524.01291592866380932262
6,21,27,36,38,.00000003928300572096,436900071012030753008.30262681637238429132
10,27,28,36,37,.00000003008373884637,435599945018162696828.11811578965645207529
7,27,36,37,38,.00000003901470733271,429968016263971351985.11511588207645725675
7,8,27,36,38,.00000003489635129611,426701769960203505719.69707822028623500242
8,27,28,37,49,.00000004154358519174,426132096265181446439.81903518248896659454
27,28,32,36,37,.00000002862278106644,419971833114908838154.67018770474370990667
27,28,29,37,40,.00000003145021404831,419971833114908838084.67488218559224632799
22,27,28,29,37,.00000003521348752418,419971833114908836614.77346628154371714693
8,27,28,29,40,.00000002813035885182,416781522683176567365.47846128950708117103
8,22,27,28,29,.00000003149638469734,416781522683176564239.61704116497449559654
21,27,28,29,37,.00000005890268630933,414538190407442863441.24796184465672455561
21,27,36,38,46,.00000002775511634823,413351131008171164757.39606547129154421099
21,28,29,36,37,.00000002866717902720,412272556315083567743.27311839408351134818
21,27,28,37,40,.00000003759118088321,412094757496279985718.05311850059474417178
21,22,27,28,37,.00000004208927090343,412094757496279982627.34243727767716209335
8,21,27,28,29,.00000005268497380248,411389156570103512400.48667732064118036871
8,21,22,27,28,.00000003764636681029,408964285164477573924.69756900052716039924
8,21,27,28,40,.00000003362309096797,408964285164477573856.53685480644401615286
6,27,28,29,37,.00000006097568163248,407120739326037321106.25415180336198902563
6,27,36,38,46,.00000002873191774709,405954920322050231127.28518930022192384571
6,28,29,36,37,.00000002967607916020,404895644876194248423.16173609479019540790
6,27,28,37,40,.00000003891414842587,404721027462798720639.30982803146682379059
6,22,27,28,37,.00000004357054225461,404721027462798717603.90212205630630125475
6,8,27,28,29,.00000005453914567708,404028052056957932784.65919047959683930164
6,8,22,27,28,.00000003897127654228,401646569572898547668.79212232956254886948
6,8,27,28,40,.00000003480640729349,401646569572898547601.85102740075058780226
6,21,27,28,37,.00000007288178942766,399484701390355495101.99874471869884064249
8,22,27,29,37,.00000003087064090214,397981910756429372715.35054616070498978587
6,21,28,36,37,.00000003547062852743,397301341256621213151.47334455501812914118
6,8,21,27,28,.00000006518845586277,396450021181660665591.10969060109006493777
6,8,21,28,36,.00000003172638213665,394283246914076539673.21322195341184503213
8,21,27,29,37,.00000005163827286287,392832776132219076858.10226095900855917025
27,28,29,37,38,.00000006392433402498,391659307589024141397.61069742923629588454
8,21,22,27,37,.00000003689844032064,390517282515475317467.53050010057592971382
8,21,27,37,40,.00000003295509555355,390517282515475317402.44428634799332410569
7,8,27,28,37,.00000006474322624452,390159765276380887302.44661751412325822861
28,29,36,37,38,.00000003111115031435,389518716684742531811.89632963974481189142
27,28,37,38,40,.00000004079595267612,389350730805819503282.10994082560026539859
22,27,28,37,38,.00000004567751966301,389350730805819501903.15943588659071529257
8,27,28,29,38,.00000005717654107931,388684072880023023556.40707313074896503678
7,8,28,36,37,.00000003150969461399,388027370032390848174.25952337966073398064
8,28,29,36,38,.00000002782708636868,386559742946010183311.30613615554192344008
8,27,28,38,40,.00000003648957004612,386393033169577018568.36826879109585985368
```